# Can't load Xamarin solution after Visual Studio 15.7.3 update

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

After updating Visual Studio 15.7.1 **into 15.7.3**, I can't load my Xamarin solution that has a Xamarin.IOs project and a Net Standard 2.0 project.

The loading project window appears loading the projects, but it freezes on loading the first project and Visual Studio goes not responding. The only way to close Visual Studio at that point is by terminating it through the Task Manager.

Is there any way can I successfully open my Xamarin solution from Visual Studio 15.7.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be happening only when you try to open the solution through Visual Studio 15.7.3 itself. That is if you try to open the solution,

- Through the **recent link** under Recent section of the *Start Page in Visual Studio*
- Through the **Open Project / Solution** under Open section of the *Start Page in Visual Studio*
- Through **File > Open > Project / Solution...** in *Visual Studio*

### Solution:

If you navigate to the directory of the solution, then **double click the solution file** (.sln file) if .sln files are set to open with Visual Studio *OR* right click on the solution file and select **Open with > Microsoft Visual Studio 2017**

Then the solution along with the projects will be successfully opened in Visual Studio 15.7.3!

**Note:** There's a ticket requesting to fix this issue at, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/266351/cant-load-xamarin-solution-after-visual-studio-157.html

### Update:

After restarting windows, then you can reopen projects as before, directly through Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

1. Disabled xamarin Extension
2. Restart VS
3. Reload droid project
4. Enabled Xamaring Extension
5. Restart VS

This worked for me